# Maven compile fails silently - Unresolved compilation problems

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have an interesting problem with a spring webapp maven build. When being built inside eclipse everything is fine yet when built via maven and deployed to a tomcat 8 container the webapp fails on startup with the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: FilterConfig
```

Now I tried all the obvious and well documented dependency issues (setting scope provided on the javax.servlet-api & jsp-api import and making sure they are of the latest versions as this is a Java 8 project). I have made sure all of the complier plugins are of the latest versions:

maven-war-plugin
3.1.0

maven-compiler-plugin
3.6.1

yet the webapp fails to start with no errors being shown in the maven build console output. After much head-scratching and painstaking comparison between the (working) eclipse build and the mysteriously failing maven equivalent it was discovered that inside some of the class files generated by maven were texts describing compilation problems. (The following was extracted from the "Open With > Text Editor" option in eclipse against the .class file - some of the characters had to be omitted as they wouldn't copy correctly)

```
Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import javax.servlet.Filter cannot be resolved
    The import javax.servlet.FilterChain cannot be resolved
    The import javax.servlet.FilterConfig cannot be resolved
    The import javax.servlet.ServletException cannot be resolved
    The import javax.servlet.ServletRequest cannot be resolved
    The import javax.servlet.ServletResponse cannot be resolved
    The import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest cannot be resolved
    The import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession cannot be resolved
    Filter cannot be resolved to a type
    FilterConfig cannot be resolved to a type
    ServletException cannot be resolved to a type
    ServletRequest cannot be resolved to a type
    ServletResponse cannot be resolved to a type
    FilterChain cannot be resolved to a type
    ServletException cannot be resolved to a type
    HttpServletRequest cannot be resolved to a type
    HttpServletRequest cannot be resolved to a type
    HttpSession cannot be resolved to a type
```

I cannot understand how the maven process appears to complete successfully and that no errors are shown with any of the mvn goals I've tried

mvn complier:compile

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building xxxx 2.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ EBPP ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) @ EBPP ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.413 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-28T15:11:45+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/213M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

the above but with the -x showed a lot of debugging output but nothing to suggest compile problems, in fact it states that the class-file identified unresolved dependencies are included

```
...
[DEBUG]    javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided  
[DEBUG]    org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]    commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile 
[DEBUG]    commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile 
[DEBUG]    javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.2:provided 
...
```

mvn dependency:build-classpath

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building xxxx 2.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:build-classpath (default-cli) @ EBPP ---
[INFO] Dependencies classpath:
C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\webflow\spring-webflow\2.4.5.RELEASE\spring-webflow-2.4.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\opensymphony\ognl\2.6.11\ognl-2.6.11.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\webflow\spring-binding\2.4.5.RELEASE\spring-binding-2.4.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\webflow\spring-js\2.4.5.RELEASE\spring-js-2.4.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\webflow\spring-js-resources\2.4.5.RELEASE\spring-js-resources-2.4.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.3.0.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.3.0.RELEASE\spring-context-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.3.0.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.3.0.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\4.3.0.RELEASE\spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\4.3.0.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.3.9.RELEASE\spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\com\xxxxxxx\ebpp\JComms\2.0.1\JComms-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4.7\mail-1.4.7.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.1\httpclient-4.5.1.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.3\httpcore-4.4.3.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\commons-httpclient\commons-httpclient\3.1\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\com\xxxxxxx\ebpp\JCore\2.0.1\JCore-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.1.0\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\org\apache\velocity\velocity\1.7\velocity-1.7.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.4\commons-lang-2.4.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\jsp\jsp-api\2.2\jsp-api-2.2.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\junit\junit\3.8.2\junit-3.8.2.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context-support\4.3.9.RELEASE\spring-context-support-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\com\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxx\440\xxxxxxx-440.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.331 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-28T15:13:05+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/213M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

mvn validate

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building xxx 2.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.109 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-28T15:15:32+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/213M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I really am stumped. I'm presuming maven is using a different compiler from eclipse but I really have run out of ideas.

Has anyone else encountered this before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A long shot, but perhaps: do you have "Build automatically" checked in eclipse, but running via command line? Eclipse does its own building, and might try to do so, in the same folder, at the same time as maven, and things could clash.

Comment: hummm, I usually do the maven build inside eclipse "run as > Maven clean", then "run as >Maven install". Just to be sure I tried with build automatically off and it's still a problem. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when comparing this project to another successful project (that were both converted from Java 4), on the hunch that using non standard directory names was the cause for mavens erratic behavior (while copying the warSourceDirectory). I analysed the (now called) WebRoot > WEB-INF > classes directory and discovered that for the problematic app this had been populated, with you've guessed it - incorrectly compiled class files! Clearly the war plugin copied these bad files over the top of the files Maven had, in the same build process just successfully complied - hence no error.

I am unsure why the bad files were there as they were not in the old Java 4 project. I suspect that they must have been created somehow during a previous failed maven build using incorrect settings.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's a combination of eclipse building your files with compilation errors (yes, Eclipse can do that: if you never reach the un-compilable code, then you don't even get errors) and Maven not cleaning the output of Eclipse first.

Then Maven sees that the file is up-to-date, and doesn't overwrite it.

I suggest the following (to check if I'm right):

- Turn off Eclipse's automatic build (or stop eclipse altogether).
- Run a Maven target, such as `package` but also run `clean` (i.e. `mvn clean package`); the point is to be 100% sure that Maven builds those files and not Eclipse.
- Maven should now report compilation errors.

As for the error itself, it looks like you are indeed missing a dependency (but probably in Eclipse's classpath, not Maven's).

Comment: So I tried switching off eclipses' build automatically, then closed down eclipse entirely after performing a project clean (with start a build unchecked). I then ran mvn package in the projects directory (that did not have a target directory at this point). The mvn command completed successfully, with no errors and created a target directory. I then re-opened eclipse to view the contents of the generated class file (as my text editors do not show the same view) ... Alas it is the same.

Comment: Incidentally in my eclipse build path I only use Maven Dependencies, this once expanded in the project properties window shows the javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar present. ... I think that maven must be leaving these unresolved compilation issues there in the hope that the code will be unreached? The code is in fact a filter specified in web.xml, so blows on startup.

Comment: Interestingly I have just noticed that inside the target directory there is a classes directory with (what appear to be) correctly compiled classes inside. This is in addition to the project's .war file and compilation folder (that contain the incorrectly built classes).

Comment: Eclipse classpath and Maven's can differ slightly. Why is this jar showing as `provided`? Shouldn't it be `compile`? javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Andrei. I located the cause (answered below)